# Creating minLength exception in jQueryUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a collection of data whereby the requirements are for the autocomplete to show results after 3 characters have been written. However, there is one piece of data that which is only two characters long.. ('LG').

So my question is;

Is there a way to keep :`minLength:3` whilst creating an exception for when certain characters are typed, such as ('LG')?

I've been trying to hard code the result within the success parameter, as can be seen below but it's not working as intended. I'm hoping I'm on the right track though?

Here is a code snippet, and plunk of complete code thus far;

```
 success: function (LG, resp) {
         if (LG.length === 2) {
                LG.push({
                  label: 'LG',
                  value: 'LG',
                });
            }
        response(LG);

        var results = [];
        $.each(resp.Q0, function(k, v) {
          if (v.indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
            results.push(v);
          }
        });
        response(results);
      }
    });
  },
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wfAoi0sZDdDd0pCufQi9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an option is modify the minChars and modify the success function. 
Here i add you the code, tell me if would suit your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#_Q0').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "brands.json",
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: "GET",
      success: function (resp) {
        var results = [];
        $.each(resp.Q0, function(k, v) {
           if (request.term.length >= 3 && v.indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
                    results.push(v);
           }
           if (request.term.length == 2 && request.term.toUpperCase() == v) {
                    results.push(v);
           }
        });
        response(results);
      }
    });
  },
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 2,
  response: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.content.length) {
      var noResult = {
        value: "",
        label: "No results found"
      };
      ui.content.push(noResult);
    } 
  }
});
var render = $('#_Q0').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu;
$('#_Q0').autocomplete('instance')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  items.push({
    label: 'AUTRE MARQUE',
    value: 'AUTRE MARQUE',
    last: true
  });
  render.call(this, ul, items);
};
  }, 100);
});
```

The point i dont like too much is i had to hardcode the minChars into the success function, maybe we could find the way to recover the value from the property "minChars"

https://plnkr.co/edit/ygtMteIH1J5EI5KUMU3C?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, it seems that when testing you're code the options in the dropdown disappear once you exceed either 2 or 3 characters, and all the items appear after typing in the first two characters. Perhaps a solution could be to replicate the whole code and changing the second instance to retrieve data from a different JSON data set which contains brands with only 2 characters? So essentially, I could use $.each(resp.3charData) and $.each(resp.2charData)?

Comment: Sorry i got a mistake, you have to add the condition >= minChars in the first condition. I edited my response

Comment: oh okay! yes, that definitely bring's it closer to what I intend ! Thank you. However, one minor thing is that the 'no results found' will appear after two characters have been entered. Is their a way to modify this also? perhaps by adding something like this ;       if (!ui.content && ui.content.length == 3)

Comment: I am afraid now the "No results found" will be triggered when the user enter 2 characters or more, is the only way to add the condition for key words of 2 letters as "LG", then i think you will have to live with the trigger at 2 characters

Comment: Okay, well I suppose you can't have everything! thanks, for the help !